# Как принудительно отрисовать (обновить) NSSliderCell?

Tags: xcode, swift, gui, macos, cocoa

Имеется класс, унаследованный от `NSSliderCell`, с переопределенным методом `drawBar(inside aRect: NSRect, flipped: Bool)`.

Мне нужно, видимо, вызывать этот метод каждый раз при изменении так же добавленного мной в дочерний класс параметра.

Речь об отрисовке полосы буферизации и параметре со значением, соответствующем прогрессу этого дела от нуля вплоть до `maxValue`.

Слайдер обновляется (перерисовывается) только при изменениях значения его прогресса (`floatValue` или `doubleValue`), при смене положения knob'а. 
Как мне заставить слайдер перерисоваться при изменении значения `bufferedValue`?
Что нужно вчекрыжить в `didSet{}` этого параметра?

Есть, конечно дикий workaroud - изменять `self.doubleValue` на какое-то мизерное значение туда-сюда. Тогда нужный метод запускается, видимо, из didSet'а или сеттера этого параметра.

Но это, конечно же, не дело.

Comment: покажите код хоть какой то

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko уточнил, если и так будет непонятно, полезу за кодом.

Comment: вам надо прицепить KVO к bufferedValue и перерисовывать слайдер, когда значение меняется?

Comment: bufferedValue - новый параметр класса, унаследованного от NSSliderCell. Мне нужно чтобы при изменении значения этого параметра (объектов этого нового класса) извне, перерисовывался слайдер. Как при изменении doubleValue, например, только не общий прогресс, а полоса буферизации. Отрисовка всего этого дела уже написана в переопределенном drawBar. Так вот, полагаю, этого (перерисовки) я могу добиться, поместив вызов какой-то функции в didSet bufferedValue. Только вот я никак не понимаю какой и как. Думал что вызов напрямую самой drawRect не отрабатывает. Он отрабатывает. Но раз из пяти вызовов